# How to force a specific .Net version (down to the minor/minor-minor version number) to be used when running an app

Tags: c#, .net, version

I have installed different versions of the .Net framework on my machine and I wonder if it is possible to choose one specifically when running a .Net app.

I tried setting it in App.config like so:

```xml
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
```

but when I check the version being actually used via [`RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription?view=net-6.0), the output is `.NET Framework 4.8.4261.0`, even though v4.6.1 is installed on my system.

How can one test a specific version, e.g. to see whether a bug shows on a particular .Net version?

Comment: The documentation states that it applies to .Net Framework 4.7.1 and up.

Comment: I would probably recommend using separate virtual machines for testing and isolating bugs. That lets you have full control over most environmental parameters.

Comment: @JonasH That would surely work, but I'd like to avoid having to set up a virtual machine. Also, what is the point of having mulitple versions installed, if they cannot actually be used. I'd like to believe there is some way to use one of the installed versions, rather than just the latest one.

Comment: Side note: since most of full framework updates are in-place (replacing the existing version) you may want to clarify what exactly you did for "I have installed different versions of the .Net framework on my machine".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The installed version all list up in the "uninstall" section of the control panel, so it looks like they are installed side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the .NET Version for your application by changing it in your application propreties, in Visual Studio right-click on your project and then propreties, under Application tab.

Then Visual Studio will update config files automatically.